# using for loop with push() to create arrays within a new array

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project where I need to declare `customsItem` formatted in a particular way.
The format given is:

```
var customsItem = {
    "description":"T-Shirt",
    "quantity":20,
    "net_weight":"1",
    "mass_unit":"lb",
    "value_amount":"200",
    "value_currency":"USD",
    "origin_country":"US",
};
```

In my project however, I have multiple descriptions, so I need to make `customsItem` an array containing both.
I have array `itemInCart` =

```
[
  {
    itemDescription: 't-shirt',
    qty: 1,
    pre_orderQty: 1,
    price: 30,
    weight: 8
  },
  {
    itemDescription: 'pants',
    qty: 0,
    pre_orderQty: 1,
    price: 40,
    weight: 5
  }
]
```

I need to get these items in the correct format and within an array called `customsItem`. I thought to do this using a for loop with `push()`. Currently, I'm not getting anything when I try to `console.log(customsItem)`, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve the results that I am trying to get. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to correctly get the results that I need. Thank you!

```
const customsItem = [];
for (var item of itemInCart) {
    const items = {
    "description":item.itemDescription,
    "quantity":item.qty + item.pre_orderQty,
    "net_weight":item.weight,
    "mass_unit":"oz",
    "value_amount":item.price,
    "value_currency":"USD",
    "origin_country":"US",
    }
    customItem.push(
        items
     )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not pushing into the correct array:

```
const customsItem = [];
for (var item of itemInCart) {
    const items = {
    "description":item.itemDescription,
    "quantity":item.qty + item.pre_orderQty,
    "net_weight":item.weight,
    "mass_unit":"oz",
    "value_amount":item.price,
    "value_currency":"USD",
    "origin_country":"US",
    }
    customItem.push(          <---- needs to be customsItem.push
        items
     )
}
```